# Bacula: What's the goal of the option "Limit backup to one filesystem?"

Tags: linux, backup, filesystems

I'm using Bacula via webmin.

In the control panel, in the Create File Set page, there is the option

> Limit backup to one filesystem?

with the options: Yes / No / Default.

Could you explain me what does it mean? In which situation could I have more than one filesystem? What does Bacula mean exactly with "filesystem" word?

I googled with the test of the option, I got only 3, useless, results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux, filesystems can be mounted within other filesystems. For instance a system with root, home, and boot filesystems are typically mounted as:

```
/ (root)
/home
/boot
```

Where the home and boot filesystems are mounted into the / (root) filesystem.

In this example, if you configure Bacula to backup / (root) and have *Limit backup to one filesystem?* set to **Yes**, Bacula will backup the root filesystem, but not the files under /home and /boot.